# Detect duplicate POSTs

Tags: scala, heroku, concurrency, concurrenthashmap, playframework-2.3

I'm working on a play framework 2 based prototype where one of the requirements is to filter duplicate post requests from clients. Its a prototype and trying to hack one out quick and dirty. I have the following data structure and code to keep track of duplicates.

```
public class DuplicityService {

    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String,List<String>> keyIps = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,List<String>>();

    public static boolean isDuplicate(String key,String ip){
        List<String> value = keyIps.get(key);
        return value != null && value.contains(ip);
    }

    public static void remove(String key){
        keyIps.remove(key);
    }

    public static void add(String key,String ip){
        List<String> value = keyIps.get(key);
        if(value == null){
            value = new ArrayList<String>();

        }
        value.add(ip);
        keyIps.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I use this in my Controllers as such

```
def submitResponse(qkey:String) = CorsAction(parse.json){
               req =>
      val json = req.body
      val key = json.\("Key").as[String]
       ....
        if(DuplicityService.isDuplicate(key,req.remoteAddress)){
          ...
          BadRequest("Duplicate Response  " + key)
        }
        else{
             ...
              DuplicityService.add(key,req.remoteAddress)

              Ok(json)
             ...
          }  
  }
```

And remove the key from the concurrent hashmap in a separate controller method

```
def publish(key: String) = Authenticated{

    ...
    DuplicityService.remove(key)
    ...
  }
```

Now the problem is that while **testing manually on my local machine** it works fine. I'm able to correctly identify duplicate post requests from same IP address.

However, on heroku, this doesn't work. I'm able to make duplicate post requests from same client.

I have a basic instance of a Heroku play 2 server.

Any pointers or help will be much appreciated.

PS: Without using a database, are there better ways to do something what I'm attempting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect Heroku might create more than 1 JVM instance either flushing out or duplicating your static singleton.

Using Memcached or equivalent (but probably not a fully fledged DB because you're essentially just caching) would be my preference.

Alternatively, depending on the scalability needs of your application, to avoid the cache becoming a bottleneck, you might want to design your application in a way that deals with duplicate requests in a more lazy and decentralized manner; something in the spirit of http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency.

Comment: Thank you. Follow up dumb question: for eventual consistency you HAVE to use something like MongoDB right?

Comment: I don't think so but I can't give an sxhaustive asnwer; feel free to create another question.